# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null of the DOG API

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, api

I'm tryng to import the DOG API to my Dog shelter application. I have all the endpoints of the project on api/index.js where exported the URL from the library:

```
export const BREEDS_URL = () => API.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
```

For some reason output the error cannot read addEventListener of null.
The code of my home , where I want to import the filter of the dogs is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Grow, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {BREEDS_URL} from '../../api/index.js';


import { getPosts } from '../../actions/posts';
import Posts from '../Posts/Posts';
import Form from '../Form/Form';

const Home = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const select = document.querySelector('.breeds');
  
  fetch(BREEDS_URL)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      const breedsObject = data.message;
      const breedsArray = Object.keys(breedsObject);
      for (let i = 0; i < breedsArray.length; i++) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = breedsArray[i];
        option.innerText = breedsArray[i];
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
      console.log(breedsArray);
    });
  
  select.addEventListener('change', event => {
    let url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${event.target.value}/images/random`;
    getDoggo(url);
  });
  
  const img = document.querySelector('.dog-img');
  const spinner = document.querySelector('.spinner');
  
  const getDoggo = url => {
    spinner.classList.add('show');
    img.classList.remove('show');
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        img.src = data.message;
      });
  };
  
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    spinner.classList.remove('show');
    img.classList.add('show');
  });



  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [currentId, dispatch]);


  return (
    <Grow in>
      <Container>
        <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
            <Posts setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <Form currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <div class="container">
              <header>
                <h1>Dog Helper</h1>
                <select class="breeds" ></select>
              </header>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="spinner">
                </div>
                <img
                  src="http://placecorgi.com/260/180"
                  class="dog-img show"
                  alt="friendly and intimate - man's best friend"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Grow>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Any idea???

Comment: The `<select>` isn't created until after the function returns.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: At the end of `Home()` you return the HTML that contains `<select class="breeds">`. So it gets added to the DOM when the function returns. So you can't use `querySelector(".breeds")` earlier in the function, because it won't find it.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Can you please help to fix? I'm hours tryng

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. But you need to do the fetch and addeventlistener in another function that's called *after* the element is added to the DOM.

Comment: You are mixing plain Js with React which is not a good idea, You can use the useRef hook instead of queryselector to get the element

Comment: I tried useRef and it gives me the same problem